# Issues saving via VBA suddenly in OneDrive/SharePoint?

Tags: document-library, permissions, error, file, vba

I'm using this, and it has been working like a charm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734706/excels-fullname-property-with-onedrive

But suddenly I'm getting an issue that I can't save an email attachment (file) to a folder in OneDrive anymore. Anyone else seeing this issue?

And I have no idea where to start? The code getting the file path fine, but cant save it there, it is giving me this error:

> An the error is run-time error-2147024773 (8007007b) cannot save the attachment. filename or directory name is not valid.

Really messed up some Scripts I have.

How can I see if there's a permission problem in SharePoint for this?

I'm the "owner" and have had no issues before?

Comment: Anyone know why it suddenly cant save to onedrive anymore?
How do i check permissions or something like that?